# Cant create procedure in MySql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I'm racking my head, I can't figure out what the problem is. This SQL code does not work on MySQL 5.7

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE sp_create_message (queue_name VARCHAR(50), data TEXT)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @stm = CONCAT('
        INSERT INTO queue_', queue_name, '
            (data)
        VALUES
            (?)
    ');
    PREPARE stm FROM @stm;
    EXECUTE stm USING data;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
END //
```

#1064 - You have an error in the request. Check the documentation for the MySQL version you are using for the correct syntax about " on line 4

i dont now whats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use the value directly from an input parameter,the USING clause in the EXECUTE statement only accept user variables. Try modify the code like this:

```
set @data=data;
EXECUTE stm USING @data;
```

Comment: no. that no working. 
#1064 - You have an error in the request. Check the documentation for the MySQL version you are using for the correct syntax about " on line 4

i use this code:

`CREATE  PROCEDURE sp_create_message (queue_name VARCHAR(50), data TEXT)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @data=data;
    SET @stm = CONCAT('
        INSERT INTO queue_', queue_name, '
            (data)
        VALUES
            (?)
    ');
    PREPARE stm FROM @stm;
    EXECUTE stm USING @data;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
END //`

Comment: I copy & pasted your code (except I added some margin and line break to make it more readable)  on workbench and created the procedure without fail. Could you provide the MySQL version and workbench of yours ?

Comment: By the way, could you please refrain from using keywords and reserved words for you column names or variable names? Some MySQL version could not cope with them properly. In this case , the word 'data' should not be used lightly. If you have to use it , at lease embrace them with backtick . i.e  `data`

Comment: thank you all for your help and advice. the answer was found, I did not use delimiter in creating the procedure, and because of this the code did not work, I started using local variables and added delimiters, everything worked! thanks again to everyone!

Comment: Glad to hear that.